# como hago para que la persona que ejecute el programa elija la ruta y el nombre con el que queden almacenados los archivos txt que genera mi programa

Tags: python, archivo

Hola amigos he creado un programa que subdivide un archivo txt cargado por el usuario del programa en diferentes archivos txt, quiero saber como puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda poner el nombre a los archivos generados por el programa y no se nombren de manera aleatoria. como el usuario podría escoger la ruta de guardado

```
#importar archivo
archivo_ruta=str(input('introduzca la ruta del archivo, no olvide poner el .txt al final ejemplo "archivo.txt" : '))

archivo = open(archivo_ruta,'r',encoding="utf8")
letra = archivo.read()


#cantidad inicial de archivos a crear  
print('__________________________________________')
num_car = len(letra)

if (num_car/280) == (int(num_car/280)):
    divisiones = num_car//280
else:
    divisiones = num_car//280+1
    
print('numero de caracteres del texto introducido ',num_car) #numrto de caracteres del texto 
print('numero de divisiones totales',divisiones) #numero de divisiones inicial 

print('el archivo tiene',num_car,'caracteres y tiene',divisiones,'divisiones ')
try:
    opcion = int(input("si desea continuar introduzca (1) "))

    print('_________________________________________')

    inicio = 0
    n_t=0 
    if opcion == 1:
        #inicio = 0
    
        #n_t=0 
        for i in range(divisiones): #va a correr la cantidad de divisiones inicial 
            fin = inicio+280 # 0+280 
            n_t=i+1
            #print("numero de iteraciones tuit ",n_t)
            #la condicion evita que se salga del index range
            if fin< num_car:# si fin es menor que el numero de caracteres 
            
                #aqui busca si las paabras quedam cortadas
                while letra[fin] !=" ": 
                    if letra[fin+1] == " ":
                        break            
                    fin -= 1
            print(letra[inicio:fin])
        
            with open(f'tuit{i+1}.txt','w') as twf: #aqui guardo mi serie de archivos como twf
                #twf = input('escriba el nombre del archivo en el que se va a guardar el tuit 1')
                twf.write(letra[inicio:fin])
            inicio = fin 
            print(n_t,'/',divisiones)
            print('______________________________________________')
    else:
        print('fin ')
except:
    print('fin')
```

mi duda esta en la linea en donde empleo el with, como podría yo usar otro comando para que no se guarde por defecto, sino que pueda ejecutar un input para que el usuario coloque el mismo el nombre

```
with open(f'tuit{i+1}.txt','w') as twf: #aqui guardo mi serie de archivos como twf
                    #twf = input('escriba el nombre del archivo en el que se va a guardar el tuit 1')
```

es decir donde comento el input, podria agregar una forma donde el usuario pueda ponerle un nombre al archivo que crea mi programa, intente hacerlo así, pero me marca error. por eso lo comenté

Comment: Pero tu codigo ya pide valores por teclado, y tenes lo que pedis escrito en un comentario. cual es el problema?

Comment: No queda muy claro el problema que tienes y que es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: hola christian, lo que pasa es que quiero que el usuario pueda darle un nombre al archivo txt que llevaria el nombre twf por defecto, intenté con un input, pero no pude. realmente no sé como pueda agregar esta función a mi código

Comment: con `with open(archivo_ruta,'w') as twf:` y listo

Comment: @gbianchi mi problema está en como puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda darle un nombre al archivo generado teniendo en cuenta que este va a ser pedido el n numero de veces que se parta el archivo principal

Comment: @Christian muchas gracias por tu aporte, sin embargo en este caso que me dices `'with open(archivo_ruta,'w') as twf`  lo que hace es reemplazar la primera división en el archivo que cargue al inicio

Comment: Tu problema no es de python, es de logica. Tal vez no tengas que usar with, y solamente debas hacer un ciclo tradicional, pero lo que tenes que hacer es antes de grabar un archivo, pedirle al usuario que te diga el nombre...

Comment: @gbianchi `with` se usa para evitar cerrar el archivo nosotros mismo, pues al final de bloque esta *built in function* se encarga de hacerlo

Comment: Y bueno, antes del with, pedir en un input el nombre del archivo.. sigo viendo que es solamente un problema de logica.. si with recibe en un string el nombre del archivo, el mismo codigo tiene la solucion al problema....

Comment: @MiguelGomez al hacer `with open(...) ....` estas abriendo un archivo en modo de escritura. No entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer, pues con lo que te dije ya tendrías todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añadir la extensión `.txt` al nombre del archivo que le quieres dar, te permite escoger el nombre del archivo.

```
nombre = input('Ingresa el nombre que le quieres dar al arhivo: ') # Pides el nombre del archivo al usuario
```

Concatena el `nombre` con `.txt`, recuerda que si el archivo ya existe lo reemplazará, dependiendo de lo que hagas con el, en este caso solo escribí 'ejemplo'

```
with open(f'{nombre}.txt', 'w') as f: # Abres el archivo, simplemente le añades la extension .txt al nombre
    f.write('Ejemplo')
    f.close()
```

Comment: 1. eso ya lo hace 2. al utilizar `with` no es necesario cerrar el archivo, por lo que ese `f.close()` sobra

Comment: Gracias por la observación :)

Comment: @DADAS Muchas gracias por tu aporte, agregué el `nombre = input("nombre del archivo ") `  con el `with open(f'{nombre}.txt','w') as twf` y `twf.write(letra[inicio:fin])`. logró que mi usuario elija efectivamente el nombre del archivo, sin embargo aun hay un lio cuando el usuario escribe el mismo nombre se reemplaza el archivo. debo trabajar en eso, sin embargo esta perfecto para lo que estaba buscando

Comment: @Christian gracias por tus observaciones no agregue el `.close `